# jQuery, show an element AFTER the page has loaded

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with a jQuery tabbed content script in that, very briefly, as the page is loading all of the tabs stack up on top of each other so what I want to be able to do is load the element, but hide it until the rest of the page has loaded and then fade it in, hopefully, without any stacking issues.

Here's [a sample URL](http://www.robotwp.com/rokk/bisnet/) with the existing problem, as you should be able to see, the tabbed content loads but looks "stacked".

I'm open to other suggestions if anyone knows of a better method.

Comment: hide the content (`display:none`) with CSS then set it to (`block` or `inline`) when ready ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could hide it by default, eg:

```
<ul class="side-nav z-tabs-nav z-tabs-desktop z-hide-menu" 
    id="stacktabs" style="display:none">
```

And then add this js to the bottom of your page:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    jQuery('#stacktabs').fadeIn(1000);
} );
```

Please note:

1. I've added an ID to your `ul` tag because you have two lists for mobile and non-mobile devices. I guess you need to fade in only one;
2. you could specify the fadein speed in milliseconds as the argument of the `fadeIn()` function;
3. I've used `jQuery()` instead of `$()` to avoid conflicts with other libraries.